# Spivak, Ch. 23, "Infinite Series", Problem 17: Prove that $\int_0^\infty \left |\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right |dx$ diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

The following problem is from Ch. 23 "Infinite Series" of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 17. Problem 19-43 shows that the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}{x} dx$ converges.
>
> Prove that $\int_0^\infty \left |\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right |dx$
> diverges.

In a separate question, [I ask about the solution manual solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571310/spivak-ch-23-infinite-series-problem-17-understanding-solution-manual-sol).

The current question regards if the following solution is correct, and how to make it more rigorous if it is correct.

Let $f(x)=\left |\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right |$. I first plotted the function and considered triangular areas as shown below.

[image]

The areas of the triangles form a sequence

$$\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{11},\frac{1}{13},...=\{b_n\}$$

It can be shown that the sequence $\left \{ \frac{1}{3+2n} \right\}=\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{9},...$ diverges using the ratio test with $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{3+2n}}=2$$

Thus, $\{b_n\}$ diverges.

**Claim:** $\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f>b_k, k=0,1,...$

If this claim is true, then

$$\int\limits_0^\infty f = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \int\limits_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f>\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_n=\infty$$

Is this proof correct?

How can we prove the claim made above?

Comment: You can formalize the triangle argument using the fact that if $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for $x \in I$ then 
$\displaystyle \int_I f(x) dx \geq \int_I g(x) dx$

Comment: But how do I show that in fact $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for $x\in I$? It seems I'd need to show that $f$ is concave, because then this means that the graph of $f$ lies above the lines forming the top two edges of a triangular area.

Comment: @OliverDíaz No that question does not address the question above, which is about a specific step in a specific proof. The linked question contains a variety of proofs, but not the one asked about above.

Comment: @evianpring: This [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2288682/121671) basically uses the standard method, but the answerer is omitting the details. The geometric idea is to build a a triangle with base $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi)$ and an appropriate hight, or the use the bound $\frac{|\sin t|}{(k+1)\pi}\leq \frac{|\sin t|}{t}\leq \frac{1}{k\pi}$ for $k\pi\leq t\leq (k+1)\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not looking at the book so I don't know what properties are available to you, but one of the most basic properties of integrals is that if $f\geq g$ then
$$
\int_a^b f\geq\int_a^b g,
$$
which justifies your claim.

The inequality can be justified by noticing that the equation of the triangle on the interval $[k\pi, (k+1)\pi]$ is
$$
g(x)=\frac2{\pi(2k+1)}-\frac4{\pi^2(2k+1)}\Big|x-\big(k\pi+\frac\pi2\big)\Big|
$$
Let us assume $k$ even to simplify notation, but the computatios don't change much. On $[k\pi,k\pi+\frac\pi2]$,
\begin{align}
\frac{|\sin x|}x
&=\frac{\sin x}x
\geq\frac{\sin x}{k\pi+\frac\pi2}
=\frac2{\pi(2k+1)}\,\sin x.
\end{align}
So, writing $x=k\pi+t$, with $0\leq t\leq\frac\pi2$,
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi(2k+1)}{2}\,(f(x)-g(x))
&\geq\frac{\pi(2k+1)}{2}\,\frac{\sin x}x-1+\frac2\pi\,\Big(k\pi+\frac\pi2-x\Big)\\[0.3cm]
&\geq\sin x-1+\frac2\pi\,\Big(k\pi+\frac\pi2-x\Big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\sin t-1+\frac2\pi\,\Big(\frac\pi2-t\Big)\\[0.3cm]
&=\sin t-\frac2\pi\,t.
\end{align}
We want to check that $h(t)=\sin t-\frac2\pi\,t\geq0$ on $[0,\frac\pi2]$. This is a function with $h(0)=0$, and $h''(t)=-\sin t\leq 0$ on the whole interval $[0,\frac\pi2]$. This means that $h$ is concave, so for all $r\in[0,1]$
$$
0=r\,h(\frac\pi2)=h(0)+r\,\big[h(\frac\pi2)-h(0)\big]
\leq h(0+r (\frac\pi2-0))=h(r\,\frac\pi2).
$$
Thus $h(t)\geq0$ for all $t\in[0,\frac\pi2]$.

---

A slightly easier proof, where you don't have to worry about calculating the $b_k$, is to notice that $|\sin x|\geq\frac{\sqrt2}2$ if $k\pi+\frac\pi4\leq x\leq (k+1)\pi-\frac\pi4$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}f
\geq \sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{k\pi+\frac\pi4}^{(k+1)\pi-\frac\pi4}f\\[0.3cm]
&\geq\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{k\pi+\frac\pi4}^{(k+1)\pi-\frac\pi4}\frac{\sqrt2}{2(k+1)\pi}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac{\sqrt2}4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k+1}=\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: How do we show $f>g$ in this problem, though?

Comment: Well, you never gave a formula for the triangles. But you considered them to be **below** $f$.

Comment: Sure, but this is the part I mentioned about making my solution more rigorous. It seems like the triangles are below the function. My attempt to show this involved trying to show that the second derivative is negative.

Comment: I added some more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest in my opinion is the following
$$\int\limits_{\pi}^{N\pi}{|\sin x|\over x}\,dx =
\sum_{n=2}^N\int\limits_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}{|\sin x|\over x}\,dx\ge \sum_{n=2}^N{1\over n\pi}\int\limits_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}|\sin x|\,dx={2\over \pi}\sum_{n=2}^N{1\over n}$$
Another proof can be made by applying the convergence of
$$\int\limits_{2\pi}^\infty {\cos x\over x}\,dx=\int\limits_{\pi}^\infty {\cos (2x)\over x}\,dx\quad (*)$$
We have
$$|\sin x|\ge \sin^2x={1\over 2}[1-\cos(2x)]$$
Then $$\int\limits_{2\pi}^N {|\sin x|\over x}\,dx \ge {1\over 2}\int\limits_{2\pi}^N \left [{1\over x}-{\cos(2x)\over x}\right ]\,dx
\\ = {1\over 2}\int\limits_{2\pi}^N {1\over x}\,dx-{1\over 2}\int\limits_{2\pi}^N {\cos(2x)\over x}\,dx$$ When $N\to +\infty$ the first term tends to $+\infty,$ while the second is convergent.

**Remark** We can avoid applying the convergence of $(*).$ If $(*)$ diverges then the similar integral of $\sin x/x$ diverges. Hence it cannot be absolutely convergent. That's a pretty artificial argument, as $(*)$ is convergent.