# Spivak, Ch. 23, "Infinite Series", Problem 17: Understanding solution manual solution.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The following problem is from Ch. 23 "Infinite Series" of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 17. Problem 19-43 shows that the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}{x} dx$ converges.
>
> Prove that $\int_0^\infty \left |\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right |dx$
> diverges.

[I've asked about this problem before with regard to the correctness of my solution attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571172/spivak-ch-23-infinite-series-problem-17-prove-that-int-0-infty-left#4571196). I've also seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288665/the-improper-integrals-of-frac-sin-tt-and-left-frac-sin-tt-right) about this particular improper integral.

The current question, however, is specifically about the solution in the solution manual to Spivak's *Calculus*.

Here it is verbatim

> Choose $\delta>0$ so that $|\sin{x}|\geq 1/2$ on
> $(k\pi+\pi/2-\delta,k\pi+\pi/2+\delta)$. Then
>
> $$\int\limits_{k\pi+\pi/2-\delta}^{k\pi+\pi/2+\delta} \left |
>  \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right |dx\geq \frac{\delta}{k\pi+\pi/2}\tag{1}$$
>
> Since the series
>
> $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k\pi+\pi/2}$$
>
> diverges, the same is true for the integral.

But how do we obtain $(1)$?

We can depict the setup in the solution above as

[image]

It seems that (1) means that a rectangular area of height $\frac{1}{k\pi+\pi/2}$ and base $\delta$ is smaller than or equal to the area under the graph between $k\pi+\pi/2-\delta$ and $k\pi+\pi/2+\delta$.

But how is this justified?

Comment: Maybe you need to be more trusting on your work and ditch the solutions manual. They do more harm than good when used on regular basis as they hindrance your creativity (some problems may be solved in ways completely different to the Manual). I suggest you used them as the  last resource, when no much progress is done and need a hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The improper integrals of $\frac{\sin t}{t}$ and $\left|\frac{\sin t}{t}\right|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288665/the-improper-integrals-of-frac-sin-tt-and-left-frac-sin-tt-right)

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ in $(k\pi+\pi/2-\delta, k\pi+\pi/2+\delta)$, then the area under the graph in this interval is

$$A_1\geq \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\delta=\delta$$

And the area of the rectangular area of height $\frac{1}{k\pi+\pi/2}$ and base $\delta$ is

$$A_2= \frac{1}{k\pi+\pi/2}\delta<\delta$$

Hence $A_2<A_1$.

That is

$$A_1=\int\limits_{k\pi+\pi/2-\delta}^{k\pi+\pi/2+\delta} \left |
 \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \right |dx\geq \delta >\frac{\delta}{k\pi+\pi/2}=A_2$$

Answer (score 0):

The solutions manual I have has a $+\delta$ in the denominator, which makes the estimate correct. Now the divergence of the series follows by limit comparison.